# How to specify a path in routing Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have located contoller in directory `dashboard`, how to specify correct path in routing to this controller?

I have class by path:

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\PlaceController
```

But I get error that this class : does not exist

Comment: Can you show what you have in your routes file?

Comment: I have this: `Route::resource('place', 'Dashboard\PlaceController');`

Comment: make sure you have this line in top of controller: namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;

Comment: I tried to set: `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;` then I get: `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\Controller' not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel uses PSR-4 namespaces, so you need to make sure controller is in correct namespace:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PlaceController extends....
```

If namespace is correct, try to run `composer dumpauto` command.

Comment: Yes, buy when I do: `class OrderController extends Controller` It search `Controller.php` file in Dashboard

Comment: `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\Controller' not found` in line `extends Controller`

Comment: Add `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` clause to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a example :

## Laravel 5.2 :

1. create a directory on >> App >> Http >> Controllers >> Dashboard
2. create a file >>App>>Http>>Controllers>>Dashboard>> PlaceController.php

### PlaceController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;


class PlaceController extends Controller
{
   // write your functions
}
```

## command line

on command line : `composer dump-autoload`